# Set periodic in Vertx does not getting triggered every time

Tags: java, vert.x

Below is my `setPeriodic` code

```
         MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        vertx.setPeriodic(300000, handler -> myClass.myHandler());
```

I am running in Vertx 3.5.3 in Kubernetes. There is a logger inside `myHandler` but the log does not get printed every 5 minutes (time is in milliseconds). The pod is serving request properly throughout the day but the log line in `myHandler` does not get printed every 5 minutes. Logs gets printed for 1 hour and then stops for sometime. The behaviour is random.

**EDIT**

Below is my handler logic. I am using slf4j logger.

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

 public class MyClass {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

 private Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();

 public void myHandler() {
    data = new HashMap<>();
    LOGGER.info("Refreshed  cache ");
   }
}
```

Comment: i doubt that your problem is in this line

Comment: @taygetos i have one more similar setPeriodic that shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Still, this line doesn't log anything. You probably should share more code and what logging framework you use. Or if you really think that the setPeriodic is not working then test it by calling the logger in place: vertx.setPeriodic(300000, p -> logger.info("hello world"))

Comment: @taygetos updated code.

Comment: I think there might be some settings to block duplicate log output. Can you test and add time in log line. "Refresh cache {}", System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 0):

you use lambda in a wrong way. vertx.setPeriodic(300000, handler -> myClass.myHandler()); will do nothing, you should use vertx.setPeriodic(300000, myClass.myHandler());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).